# Поиск и изменение структуры в составе массива

Tags: массивы, swift, struct

Помогите, найти лучший вариант реализации.
Дано: Массив со структурами. Необходимо внести изменения в конкретную структуру.

Реализация очень топорная, уверен, что есть то чего я не знаю и намного элегантней вариант

```
import Foundation

struct Person {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

var contacts: [Person] = [
    Person(id: 1, name: "Alex"),
    Person(id: 2, name: "Stiv"),
    Person(id: 3, name: "Joy")
]


func renamePerson(id: Int, name: String, array: [Person]) -> [Person] {

    var result: [Person] = []

    for i in array {
        if i.id == id {
            result.append(Person(id: i.id, name: name))
        } else {
            result.append(i)
        }
    }
    return result
}

contacts = renamePerson(id: 1, name: "Sasha", array: contacts)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно изменить тип `Person` на `class`, чтобы можно было изменять объекты массива, и переписать код так. Если же тип `struct` нужно сохранить, то ваш вариант в данном случае по-моему единственно возможный

```
class Person {
    var id: Int
    var name: String

    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

func renamePerson(id: Int, name: String, array: [Person]) {

    // вариант 1
    for i in array {
        if i.id == id {
            i.name = name
            break
        }
    }

    // вариант 2
    array.first { $0.id == id }?.name = name
}

renamePerson(id: 1, name: "Sasha", array: contacts)
```

**Дополнение**

Можно сохранить тип `struct`, если сделать массив `inout`. Тогда возможен такой вариант

```
func renamePerson2(id: Int, name: String, array: inout [Person]) {
    for i in 0..<array.count {
        if array[i].id == id {
            array[i] = Person(id: array[i].id, name: name)
            break
        }
    }
}

renamePerson2(id: 1, name: "Sasha", array: &contacts)
```

Comment: Благодарю, все же вот где требуются знания различия структуры и класса, теперь встретил это на практике. пока ждал ответа, googl'ил и повторил вВаш второй вариант, только немного иной 
contacts.filter{$0.id == 1 && $0.name == "Sasha"}.first?.name = "rest". Подскажите с этого выражения есть возможность получить true или false, чтоб понять была ли успешна операция, пока не понял как это сделать

Comment: @SwiftProger если ответ устраивает, отметьте его галкой

Comment: @SwiftProger посмотрите еще дополнение

Comment: `first` как и `filter` возвращают опциональное значение, поэтому результат можно проверить на `nil`, если нужно проверить успешность операции

Comment: @SwiftProger кроме того, имеется метод `contains`, который как раз возвращает `bool`

Comment: @SwiftProger дополню еще касательно разницы между `first` и `filter` - `first` может быть быстрее `filter`, если у вас `id` для всех записей уникальные, так как тогда результат возвращается сразу при обнаружении первого совпадения, тогда как `filter` сначала проходится по всему массиву

Comment: Галку, поставил, первой мой вопрос был, не знал что к чему. Благодарен тебе.

Comment: а есть возможность не свойства сравнивать, а целые объекты?

Comment: @SwiftProger это отдельный вопрос и его лучше оформить отдельно, но вообще гуглим сравнение объектов в свифте

Answer (score 1):

В Swift 5/Xcode 11.5 для решения Вашей задачи можно воспользоваться функцией `map`:

```
func renamePerson(id: Int, name: String, array: [Person]) -> [Person] {
    return array.map { $0.id == id ? Person(id: id, name: name) : $0 }
}
```

Comment: Хороший вариант рефакторинга кода из вопроса, правда в остальном копирование целого массива ради изменения одного элемента не лучшее решение