# Работа с массивом структур

Tags: массивы, swift, классы, struct

Всем привет!
В ходе разбирательств по пониманию, когда использовать структуры, а когда классы, все пишут, что надо принять по дефолту понимание - если создаем какой-то свой общий тип данных, то юзайте структуры.
Но вот я столкнулся такой интересной вещью, как неизменяемость value-type по дефолту.
Допустим, у меня есть вот такой тип значения -

```
struct TestValue {
   var a: String!
   var b: String!
}
```

Допустим, у меня есть массив -

```
var array = [TestValue(a: "a1", b: "b1", TestValue(a: "a2", b: "b2")]
```

И я хочу найти в этом массиве, где проперти `a == "a1"` и изменить ее на `"hello"`

```
array.filter({$0.a == "a1"}).map({$0.a = "hello"})
```

И тут-то выдает ошибку `Cannot assign to property: '$0' is immutable`

Хм, value-type. неизменяемый. Окей.
Но у нас есть дополнительный модификатор для структур - mutating.
Попробуем так -

```
struct Test {
    var a: String
    var b: String
    
    
    mutating func changeA(newValue: String) {
        self.a = newValue
    }
}
```

Пробуем так -

```
array.filter({$0.a == "a1"}).map{ $0.changeA(newValue: "hello") }
```

И тут мы снова попадаем на туже ошибку. Почему так?

На зарубежном stackOverFlow нашел такое решение -

```
let newArray = array.map { (value) -> Test in
    if value.a == "a1" {
        var modified = value
        modified.changeA(newValue: "hello")
        return modified
    }

    return value
}
```

И все работает окей. Но получается от этого гораздо больше кода.
И вот тут мне не понятно на сколько правильно это реализуется и на сколько вообще это правильная практика.
Подскажите, как правильно в таких ситуациях преобразовывать какое-либо значение в массиве структур или вообще просто сразу же перепрыгивать на классы если такая задача стоит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я уже отвечал [на подобный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1132617/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0/1132639#1132639). В вашем случае касательно `mutating` можно бы было переписать так

```
for i in 0..<array.count {
    var value = array[i]
    
    if value.a == "a1" {
        value.changeA(newValue: "hello")
        array[i] = value
        break
    }
}
```

Данный вариант мне кажется более оптимальным, чем использование `map`, поскольку не приходится копировать ради изменения одного значения весь массив (который может быть весьма велик). Стоит ли переходить на классы - зависит от задачи, если подобные операции нужно производить многократно и не стоит задача сохранения целостных (защищенных от случайных изменений) копий массива, то возможно и стоит